# error install Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2015 on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2015

i try to install "Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2015" on my windows 7 (x86/32Bit),but a have an error like this:

```
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:41]i001: Burn v3.7.3813.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: c:\TEMP\vc_redist.x86.exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{B576E00C-35B9-4E00-8FC8-142B71641368} {3637D34E-0977-4805-A09A-FB8271D79723} 14600'
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:41]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'c:\TEMP\dd_vcredist_x86_20151212062741.log'
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:41]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'c:\TEMP\vc_redist.x86.exe'
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:41]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'c:\TEMP\'
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i100: Detect begin, 10 packages
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKey, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 0
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, state: Present, cached: Complete
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, state: Present, cached: Complete
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: Complete
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i052: Condition 'VersionNT >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT = v5.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 2) OR (VersionNT = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:42]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i200: Plan begin, 10 packages, action: Repair
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86' to value 'c:\TEMP\dd_vcredist_x86_20151212062741_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86.log'
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86' to value 'c:\TEMP\dd_vcredist_x86_20151212062741_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86.log'
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, state: Present, default requested: Repair, ba requested: Repair, execute: Repair, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, state: Present, default requested: Repair, ba requested: Repair, execute: Repair, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Repair, ba requested: Repair, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:27:45]i300: Apply begin
    [3908:5A80][2015-12-12T06:27:51]w308: Automatic updates could not be paused due to error: 0x80070422. Continuing...
    [3908:5A80][2015-12-12T06:27:51]i360: Creating a system restore point.
    [3908:5A80][2015-12-12T06:28:16]i361: Created a system restore point.
    [3908:5A80][2015-12-12T06:28:16]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
    [3908:4C9C][2015-12-12T06:28:16]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{A2563E55-3BEC-3828-8D67-E5E8B9E8B675}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86\vc_runtimeMinimum_x86.msi.
    [3908:4C9C][2015-12-12T06:28:17]i304: Verified existing payload: cab54A5CABBE7274D8A22EB58060AAB7623 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{A2563E55-3BEC-3828-8D67-E5E8B9E8B675}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86\cab1.cab.
    [3908:4C9C][2015-12-12T06:28:17]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{BE960C1C-7BAD-3DE6-8B1A-2616FE532845}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_x86\vc_runtimeAdditional_x86.msi.
    [3908:4C9C][2015-12-12T06:28:17]i304: Verified existing payload: cabB3E1576D1FEFBB979E13B1A5379E0B16 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{BE960C1C-7BAD-3DE6-8B1A-2616FE532845}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_x86\cab1.cab.
    [3908:4C9C][2015-12-12T06:28:17]i304: Verified existing payload: Windows7_MSU_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\D4036846864773E3D647F421DFE7F6CA536E307B\packages\Patch\x86\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x86.msu.
    [3908:5A80][2015-12-12T06:28:17]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{A2563E55-3BEC-3828-8D67-E5E8B9E8B675}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86\vc_runtimeMinimum_x86.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:28:27]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, result: 0x0, restart: None
    [3908:5A80][2015-12-12T06:28:27]i325: Registering dependency: {74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_x86,v14, package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86
    [3908:5A80][2015-12-12T06:28:27]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{BE960C1C-7BAD-3DE6-8B1A-2616FE532845}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_x86\vc_runtimeAdditional_x86.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:28:34]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, result: 0x0, restart: None
    [3908:5A80][2015-12-12T06:28:34]i325: Registering dependency: {74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_x86,v14, package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86
    [3908:5A80][2015-12-12T06:28:34]i301: Applying execute package: Windows7_MSU_x86, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\D4036846864773E3D647F421DFE7F6CA536E307B\packages\Patch\x86\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x86.msu, arguments: '"C:\Windows\system32\wusa.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\D4036846864773E3D647F421DFE7F6CA536E307B\packages\Patch\x86\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x86.msu" /quiet /norestart'
    [3908:5A80][2015-12-12T06:29:07]e000: Error 0x8024001e: Failed to execute MSU package.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:29:07]e000: Error 0x8024001e: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:29:07]i319: Applied execute package: Windows7_MSU_x86, result: 0x8024001e, restart: None
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:29:07]e000: Error 0x8024001e: Failed to execute MSU package.
    [3908:5A80][2015-12-12T06:29:07]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
    [3908:5A80][2015-12-12T06:29:07]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
    [3AE0:5AE4][2015-12-12T06:29:07]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x8024001e, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem but in my case I was trying to install on Windows Server 2012 R2. However the root cause should be the same.

In short, you need to install the prerequisites of KB2999226. In you case, you have to make sure your Windows 7 is running Service Pack 1.

In more details, the installation log posted by you stated that the installation for Windows Update KB2999226 failed. According to the Microsoft website [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226):

> Prerequisites To install this update, you must have [April 2014 update
>   rollup for Windows RT 8.1, Windows 8.1, and Windows Server 2012 R2
>   (2919355)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919355) installed in Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2. Or,
>   [install Service Pack 1 for Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976932).
>   Or, [install Service Pack 2 for Windows Vista and for Windows Server
>   2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948465).